# php imagerotate() function

Tags: php, image-uploading, image-rotation

My site can upload photos, the process works well on a computer. If I upload a picture through mobile is rotating. I saw it was a known problem and has a solution.
I try one of the solutions and I get an error while uploading an image to a folder:

`move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given.`

This is the code I use to rotate the image:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($new_img['tmp_name']);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {

    $file = imagecreatefromjpeg($new_img['tmp_name']);
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
            $new_img['tmp_name'] = imagerotate($file, 180, 0);
            break;

        case 6:
            $new_img['tmp_name'] = imagerotate($file, -90, 0);
            break;

        case 8:
            $new_img['tmp_name'] = imagerotate($file, 90, 0);
            break;
    }
}

move_uploaded_file($new_img['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName )
```

Comment: `imagerotate` returns a resource to the file instead of its name as a string. You'll need the filename.

Comment: I did not understand, can you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the return value of imagerotate as though it were the filename.

```
$new_img['tmp_name'] = imagerotate($file, 180, 0);
```

But it's not since [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) returns a resource.

So just change all of these lines:

```
$new_img['tmp_name'] = imagerotate($file, 180, 0);
```

with

```
imagerotate($file, 180, 0);
```

I just learned `imagerotate` existed. I'm not sure exactly how it works. You may need to save the file out at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to:

```
case 3:
    $rotate = imagerotate($file, 180, 0);
    imagejpeg($rotate,$new_img['tmp_name']);
break;
```